# React 16 just renders array of numbers into table data in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have been attempting to render words with most frequencies. I have done with fetching API.To render words with there total count.I also have setState words and mapped words array in `render()`.I was expected words with there counts. I only get numbers as `1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    1`. in table data.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Grid, Row, Col, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
class About extends Component {
  state = {
    counts: [],
    posts: [],
    words: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios({
      url:
        "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://terriblytinytales.com/test.txt",
      responseType: "text"
    })
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data;
        const newPosts = posts.split(/[0-9]+\./).map(post => post.split("?"));
        // console.log(newPosts);
        this.setState({
          posts: newPosts
        });
        return res;
      })
      .then(res => {
        const texts = res.data;
        let words = texts.replace(/[.]/g, "").split(/\s/);
        let freqMap = [];
        words.map(w => {
          if (!freqMap[w]) {
            freqMap[w] = 0;
          }
          freqMap[w] += 1;
          console.table(freqMap);
          return freqMap;
        });
        this.setState({
          words: freqMap
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
            <h1>fetched data</h1>
            <ol>
              {this.state.posts.map((post, i) => (
                <li key={i} style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
                  {post.map((p, j) => (
                    <p key={j}>{p + (j % 2 === 0 ? "?" : "")}</p>
                  ))}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ol>
          </Col>

          <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
            <Row>
              <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    {this.state.words.map((post, i) => <td key={i}>{post}</td>)}
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </Table>
            </Row>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
export default About;
```

Comment: Very difficult to tell what you're trying to achieve. How about reducing this code to a [mcve]. This may help you in the long run to identify where the issue is too.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data, and a output (How it should be the final data)

Comment: No. Have an example input, reduce the code to the minimum to show where the problem is, and the required output. Or maybe read the link in my comment.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/JwROErZfK i  want table of words with counts to be rendered but just numbers are rendering .

Comment: <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    {this.state.words.map((post, i) => <td key={i}>{post}</td>)}
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </Table>   this expected to return words with counts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is due to your implementation of [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) with your freqMap variable:

```
.then(res => {
    const texts = res.data;
    let words = texts.replace(/[.]/g, "").split(/\s/);
    let freqMap = []; // this should NOT be an array
    words.map(w => {
      if (!freqMap[w]) {
        freqMap[w] = 0;
      }
      freqMap[w] += 1;
      console.table(freqMap);
      return freqMap;
    });
    this.setState({
      words: freqMap
    });
  })
```

Arrays in javascript are not linked lists of key value pairs although javascript will not complain when you try something like `let freqMap["Word"] = 1` like you are doing in your code. this will lead to different problems especially when trying to loop over your array's contents, just like the problem you are having.

> Arrays cannot use strings as element indexes (as in an associative
>   array) but must use integers. Setting or accessing via non-integers
>   using bracket notation (or dot notation) will not set or retrieve an
>   element from the array list itself, but will set or access a variable
>   associated with that array's object property collection.

You should be using an object instead:

```
.then(res => {
    const texts = res.data;
    let words = texts.replace(/[.]/g, "").split(/\s/);
    let freqMap = {}; // this should be an object
    words.map(w => {
      if (!freqMap[w]) {
        freqMap[w] = 0;
      }
      freqMap[w] += 1;
      console.table(freqMap);
      return freqMap;
    });
    this.setState({
      words: freqMap
    });
  })
```

and then in the JSX loop over the `object.keys` which is an array of the object keys:

```
 {Object.keys(this.state.words).map((post, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
          <td>{post}</td>
          <td>{this.state.words[post]}</td>
        </tr>
  ))}
```

Comment: i have replace with the code and i am getting values in table as :   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 140  Who are you?  We're Terribly Tiny Tales – one of the world’s most celebrated social storytelling platforms We bring together a

Comment: you do realize you have numbers in your text, right? the problem is in the HTML structure you are trying to return from the JSX loop, try the updated code.

Comment: this works better it gives this error Warning: Encountered two children with the same key. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: Try this in one of the children 
<td key={i+1}>{post}</td>
<td key={i}>{this.state.words[post]}</td>

Comment: it has be reduce errors to this now Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.  and Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <tr>.

Comment: yeah I accidentaly put key={i} inside the td when it should only be inside the tr like: <tr key={i}>